# Polkadot App js UI - "waiting to make a connection to the remote endpoint and finishing API initialization

Tags: substrate, polkadot-js

I am following the tutorial ***Use the Sudo Pallet***
....Built & run the upgraded runtime - *cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 run --release -- --dev --tmp*....
*Connected to Polkadot JS Apps - https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/extrinsics?rpc=ws://127.0.0.1:9944*.

I am now receiving an error (**initializing connection - waiting to make a connection**) - and page does not load correctly.

[image]

I receive the same issue when I open ***Canvas-UI*** - e.g. if I select local node receive error *You are not connected to a node Ensure that your node is running and that your Websocket endpoint is reachable*....

[image]

Whereas when I select 'canvas test' I can connect!

[image]

Have recently upgraded FRAME runtime ***sudo pallet*** - *RuntimeVersion struct* from spec_version: 1 to spec_version: 2.

Could this be a cause?

Comment: This is likely a browser related issue. Although as you point out, you for sure want to use the same spec version in all applications. This _should_ be picked up by the API though. It will display this information on the template and on https://polkadot.js.org/apps/ 

--- Check your browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

what I did to solve that was installing Polkadot.js extension, and on settings (right left corner), select polkadot and the first option. Then press switch, and its running.

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure you are not using Firefox Browser for the polkadot UI. That is the time I have add a similar error. Use Google Chrome Browser instead.